# Local Lattice + Eureka cannot resolve hosts correctly

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I'm trying to deploy a SpringCloud Config + Netflix Eureka server in a local lattice setup following the [guide here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-and-lattice/). Unfortunately, the Eureka peers cannot reference each other, because the host IP of my Lattice install doesn't resolve on the cells.

I'm going to try it on our AWS Lattice setup, but I'd really like to get this working locally for dev/testing purposes.

Any advice?

*FWIW* The app itself spins up and I'm seeing lots of this in my logs:

```
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:08.849  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:08.855  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.config.ConfigServer          : Started ConfigServer in 18.594 seconds (JVM running for 19.859)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:08.859  INFO 4 --- [       Thread-4] c.n.eureka.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry     : Updating the replica nodes as they seem to have changed from [] to [http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/] 
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:11.397  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - Re-registering apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:11.397  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io: registering service...
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:11.429  WARN 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Action: Register  => returned status of 404 from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:11.431 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?
.22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:11.431 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - registration failedBad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:13.687  WARN 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:13.687  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:14.435  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - Re-registering apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:14.435  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io: registering service...
.22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:14.447  WARN 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Action: Register  => returned status of 404 from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:14.451 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:14.451 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - registration failedBad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:17.456  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - Re-registering apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:17.456  INFO 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io: registering service...
.22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:17.472  WARN 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Action: Register  => returned status of 404 from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:17.474 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io/eureka/apps/DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] 2015-05-22 19:29:17.482 ERROR 4 --- [pool-8-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DEMO-CONFIG-SERVICE/192.168.11.11.xip.io - registration failedBad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0] java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
22 May 13:29 [APP|0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
.22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] healthcheck failed
22 May 13:29 [HEALTH|0] Exit status 1
```

Comment: I like you pushing the envelope!  Not sure how multiple eurekas will work without knowing an IP or hostname ahead of time.  On aws netflix uses elastic IPs for eureka so hostnames always resolve.  On lattice on virtualbox, not sure what you can do.

Comment: :) glad to hear I'm not annoying you guys. My hope was to configure the hostnames via env vars. So I was spinning up peer1 saying `EUREKA_PEER=peer2.123.21.23.21.xip.io` and vice versa, but no dice there. Probably just better to leave the eurekas outside Lattice and use it for the micro-services / tasks

Answer (score 1):

well if the [url](http://eureka2.192.168.11.11.xip.io) is returning a 404, then that's a better sign because it might just be that the routing table didn't get updated yet. if you can hit the receptor url from inside a container at `receptor.192.168.11.11.xip.io`, then hitting a eureka server should be no different right?

Comment: The problem is that 192.168.11.11 is the internal IP of the boot2docker on on my host system (so it's sandboxed). The docker containers themselves (running Eureka) won't be able to contact that IP. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually pretty forward when deployed, because they will be able to resolve the IP of the brain. You just explicitly specify your hostname in your `[bootstrap|application].yml` configuration & `ltc create` command.

## Configuration settings:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${INSTANCE_HOST:localhost}
```

## Lattice creation command(s):

#### Launch Eureka Peer 1:

```
APPNAME="eureka1"
TARGET=`ltc target | grep Target | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]//g'`
LATTICE_CLI_TIMEOUT=180 ltc create $APPNAME distributedspring/config-server --memory-mb=0 -e \
  EUREKA_PEER=http://eureka2.$TARGET/eureka/ \
  -e RABBIT_HOST=rabbit-5672.$TARGET \
  -e INSTANCE_HOST=$APPNAME.$TARGET \
  -e INSTANCE_ID=$APPNAME \
  -e PREFER_IP=false \
  --no-monitor
```

#### Launch Eureka Peer 2

```
APPNAME=eureka2
TARGET=`ltc target | grep Target | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]//g'`
LATTICE_CLI_TIMEOUT=180 ltc create $APPNAME distributedspring/config-server --memory-mb=0 \
  -e EUREKA_PEER=http://eureka1.$TARGET/eureka/ \
  -e RABBIT_HOST=rabbit-5672.$TARGET \
  -e INSTANCE_HOST=$APPNAME.$TARGET \
  -e INSTANCE_ID=$APPNAME \
  -e PREFER_IP=false \
  --no-monitor
```